# OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL VS2017 Community / TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I can't sync my local git with visual studio online. This is the error I get

> Git failed with a fatal error. unable to access
>   'https://mysite.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/MajorMaintScopeChallenge/':
>   OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to
>   mysite.visualstudio.com:443

Update:
It's on a PC Windows 8

Comment: I know you say visual-studio and tfs, but now with Mac's version of visualstudio, are you on a PC or a Mac?

Comment: It's on a PC Windows 8

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I fixed it with resetting the proxy;

Running these commands in cmd;

```
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Comment: As bizarre as this seems, this is what ended up solving the issue for me! Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like an issue in your network setting then (maybe a **proxy** or a **firewall** blocking access to the remote repository), as indicated by this line:

`OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to :`

Double check if your machine is in a network with proxy/firewalls. Turn it off and try again. If you have an additional standalone pc with a direct internet connection also give a try on this machine directly.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, managed to resolve it by running the following from cmd

```
git config --global http.proxy myproxy.com:8080
```

Edit, broken after a reboot

Answer (score 2):

In my case it's a proxy issue, my company's firewall is blocking access and I don't have rights to change it. So, I switched to our company's mobile version of wifi network and managed to clone locally!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem in my case was that the Wi-Fi I was connected to was not that strong and from time to time the signal was poor. I have closed VS 2019 and reopened it again. Then, I tried to connect the VS to the Repo once again. Then, when I fetched and pulled it throw me this error again. I tried once again and then it took the necessary updates from the repo to my machine. I hope this approach - trying a couple of times (especially, when the signal is not strong) would help as well.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the proxy is being taken from the global environment variables, if applicable.

```
  [http]
        sslVerify = false
        proxy =
```

In the global **.gitconfig** file leave the proxy variable empty.