# Git Error: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to

Tags: git, ssl

I am fairly new to StackOverflow, at least for posting. Recently I started getting the following error whenever I try to do the command git pull.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://tfs.xxxxx.net/tfs/cps_azure/CAxxxx_xxxx/_git/xxxx_xxxx/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to tfs.xxxxx.net:443
```

I have tried updating my ca-bundle.crt with the key that my co-worker has and their git works. But still getting the same error.

Any help greatly appreciated!!!

--Sincerely,
Eddie

Answer (score 2):

Check if there are other differences between your colleague git (working) and yours (not working):

- git version
- OS
- git config -l (especially [`http.sslCAInfo`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-httpsslCAInfo) or `http.sslCAPath`)

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50036336/6309), your **proxy** might differ (or be set) to the one used by your colleague.

Comment: I compared my .gitconfig to the one of my coworker whose git is working and we have the same settings. I will triple check the proxy. Thanks!

Comment: @Eddie .gitconfig is only the global one. The system and local settings would be listed by a git config -l done from within the repo. And the proxy can also be set by environment variables (HTTP(S)_PROXY)